# First javascript function to check CDN load and provide local fallback

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-awesome

I'm trying to use javascript to provide a local fallback for fonts - I can't use jQuery because it won't have loaded yet and I don't want to load yet another library like yepnope if possible (plus checking for a stylesheet in yepnope is now depreciated).

I haven't found much reference for this kind of thing plus I don't know any javascript so I'm probably using the wrong search terms - sorry if this is easy.

So far I have:

```
  <!-- load fonts from cdn -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Flamenco" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- check fonts loaded via cdn and provide local fallbacks -->
  <script>
    function fontLoaded(href) {
      var fontFound = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        if (
          sheet['href'] == "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Flamenco" &&
          sheet['href'] == "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"
        ) {
          fontFound = true;
        }
      };
      return fontFound;
    }
    if (!fontLoaded('font-awesome.css')) {
      local_fallback = new CustomEvent('link');
      local_fallback.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
      local_fallback.setAttribute("href", "/assets/css/fonts.css");
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(local_fallback);
    }
</script>
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work - questions:

- I see "TypeError: local_fallback.setAttribute is not a function" in Firebug so suspect this is why the alternative font.css file isn't loading - is that right?
- I'm using '//' instead of 'http://' & 'https//' does this work with javascript?
- I'm not sure how to check if the Google font hasn't loaded `(if (!fontLoaded('font-awesome.css')))` as Google doesn't load a specific css file like font awesome - but I assume checking for fontawesome only is OK because of the && operator when checking for both stylesheets?

I also found this option but font awesome won't load:

```
<script>
    function loadLocalFonts () {
        var fonts = document.styleSheets;
        for (var i = 0, max = fonts.length; i < max; i++) {
            if (fonts[i].href == "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Flamenco" && "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css")
                return;
        }
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.href = "/assets/css/fonts.css";

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    }
    loadLocalFonts();
</script>
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply use onload event? [Stylesheet load events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Givi that looks nice and simple - but the page also states it's an HTML5 Candidate Recommendation and same goes for  [W3C as of Aug 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element). It looks like stylesheet load and error events in particular are not widely supported or are buggy? Is there a way to do this by modifying one of the examples I posted or am I way off the mark?

Comment: OK, it would seem that the last code example is actually working and the issue is that FontAwesome won't display in Chrome or Firefox (I'm using a straight local link tag to test local loading) - Safari works fine and I can see FontAwesome loading as a resource. I've tried the .htaccess for Firefox bit I'm loading locally from the same domain so am sure this isn't the issue - has anyone else seen this in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Clarification: Fontawesome is actually loading in Firefox, it's just not displaying.

Comment: Have tried the usual .htaccess Firefox fix but in this sinatnce, the font is loading from the same server (MAMP) so it made no difference.

Comment: you are not doing anything with the "href parameterer" of fontLoaded

Answer (score 0):

OK, the main issue seems to have been that I'd copied the FontAwesome css from the CDN [source](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css) which didn't work locally (as in local web server not CDN) in Firefox or Chrome for some reason.

Once I copied the FontAwesome css from the full downloaded project into the local-fonts.css file (and added declarations for Googel), I was able to provide a local fallback.

This option is probably better as javascript is only used to check if the fonts loaded via the CDN and to provide a local fallback - i.e. the initial CDN loads without requiring javascript:

```
<!-- load fonts via CDN -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Flamenco" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script>
  // check that fonts loaded via CDN
  function fontLoaded() {
    var cdnFont = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
      var font = document.styleSheets[i];
      if (
        font['href'] == "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Flamenco" &&
        font['href'] == "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"
      ) {
        cdnFont = true;
      }
    };
    return cdnFont;
  }

  // if fonts didn't load via CDN, load from local assets directory
  if (!fontLoaded('font-awesome.css')) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = "/assets/fonts/local-fonts.css";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, the above definitely works great when the CDN isn't available (if I turn off the network) but I've noticed that both local and CDN fonts load when the CDN is available. Can anyone help me with that last if statement - it seems to always be true?

Comment: It would seem that the first if statement is evaluating to false even when the font has loaded via the CDN - does anyone know why?